# How many idempotent relations are there on an $n$-element set?

Tags: co.combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids

As far as I know, it is an open problem to give a formula counting transitive relations on an $n$-element set. Is it easier to count the idempotent relations, that is relations that are both transitive and interpolative? (A relation $\rho$ is interpolative when $x\rho y\implies((\exists z)\ x\rho z \wedge z\rho y).$)

Also, if we denote the number of transitive relations on an $n$-element set by $T_n$ and the number of idempotent relations by $I_n$, can we say what the asymptotic behavior of $I_n/T_n$ is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer seems to be in Butler, K. K.-H.,The number of idempotents in (0,1)-matrix semigroups, Linear Algebra and Its Applications 5 (1972), 233–246.  I will see if I have access to the journal and will tell you more.

**Edit.**  The paper is [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379572900055/1-s2.0-0024379572900055-main.pdf?_tid=8eece726-80e4-11e2-9fcb-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1361973171_ff59deefabd771cffb05e77de54d3a1e) for free.  It counts the idempotents by D-class so it is not written down in a simple succinct formula.  If you google idempotent boolean matrix there are further papers which may be of use.

Comment: This is the answer to your first question.  I don't know about the second one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a mistake in the second question. I've changed "interpolative" to "idempotent" now.

Answer (score 5):

See OEIS sequence [A121337](http://oeis.org/A121337/) and references given there.